# Как взять содержание атрибута и вставить в другой атрибут?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование

дорогие пользователи Stack Overflow

помогите пожалуйста,

необходимо брать данные из атрибута src от блока .srciframe и размещать его в атрибут content у блока .framezzila

```js
let srciframe = document.querySelector(".srciframe").src;
let framezzila = document.querySelector(".framezzila").content;
srciframe.innerHTML = framezzila.content;
```

в инете где то такой код нашел, но он не работает
я сам с атрибутами раньше вообще не работал через js и сейчас думаю как сделать

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.querySelector(".framezzila").value = document.querySelector(".srciframe").value;
//                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//                          куда                                             откуда
```

```html
<input class="srciframe" value="123"> откуда
<input class="framezzila" value="654"> куда
```

Вместо value - соответственно прописать `src` и `content`

Comment: Спасибо добрый человек

Comment: Если ответ помог - галочку слева от ответа тык!)